# Can I use Deref<Target = Other> to inherit trait implementations from Other?

Tags: rust, traits

I have a `String` [newtype](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/new_types.html) `ErrorMessage` that I'm using for errors in a prototype crate. (I know that this is a bad practice. I will construct a proper set of distinct error types before publication.)

I need `ErrorMessage` to implement the [`Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html) trait, which is (practically) empty but  requires that it also implement the [`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) and [`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) traits, which I have done.

```rust
pub struct ErrorMessage(pub String);
impl std::error::Error for ErrorMessage {}
impl std::fmt::Display for ErrorMessage {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        self.0.fmt(f)
    }
}
impl std::fmt::Debug for ErrorMessage {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        self.0.fmt(f)
    }
}
```

[This works fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=acdecf727b3eece1743bc8c07c711ea3). However, I recently came across [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) and was wondering if it could automatically delegate trait implementations to the implementations for `String` from `self.0`.

```rust
impl std::ops::Deref for ErrorMessage {
    type Target = str;

    fn deref(&self) -> &str {
        &self.0
    }
}
```

This allows me to call methods like `.to_string()` on an `ErrorMessage`, and [deref coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/first-edition/deref-coercions.html) will let it use my `Deref` implementation to automatically find the `fmt` and `to_string` implementations on `self.0`/`*self`.

However, `ErrorMessage` *itself* isn't actually `Display` or `Debug`. If I try to `println!` or `format!` an instance directly I get an error, and [it doesn't satisfy the bounds for `Error`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b4ff80a14657fec248edfd7545dedec0).

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), ErrorMessage> {
    Err(ErrorMessage("hello world".to_string()))
}
```

```
error[E0277]: `ErrorMessage` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
 --> src/main.rs:2:6
  |
2 | impl std::error::Error for ErrorMessage {}
  |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `ErrorMessage` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
  |
  = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `ErrorMessage`
```

Is there any way to use `Deref`, `DerefMut`, or something similar to allow dereferenced values to satisfy trait bounds for the original values. I'm looking for something automatic, as an alternative to manually writing `impl` blocks to delegate each of them.

Comment: Note that your code does work if you fix the deref implementation (see https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=987a22ee51938deac9c917aa6907b29d)

Comment: you can derive Debug for ErrorMessage, but Display should still be implemented manually

Comment: @aochagavia Thanks for the correction! I've fixed the deref definition and updated my sandbox examples. Unfortunately that still doesn't let me get rid of the `impl Debug` and `impl Display` blocks.

Comment: You cannot inherit trait implementations, but for common traits you can use the [derive_more](https://jeltef.github.io/derive_more/derive_more/) crate. Does this answer your question? If yes, I can post it as an answer.

Comment: @aochagavia Thanks for the suggestion, that's good to know! but it's not quite what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there any way to use `Deref`, `DerefMut`, or something similar to allow dereferenced values to satisfy trait bounds for the original values.

No. An outer type that dereferences to an inner type does not itself implement the traits that the inner type does.

> as an alternative to manually writing `impl` blocks to delegate each of them.

Your best bet may be to create one or more macros. I'm personally holding out hope for [first-class delegation support](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2393).

Comment: The delegation RFC is super-relevant, thanks for linking!