# Rust traits on newtypes

Tags: rust, traits

Let's say I have defined a `Group` trait with all the group operations. Would it be possible to create a wrapper `AGroup` over `Group` without having to manually derive all its operations?

Basically, I'd like to have this:

```
#[derive (Copy, Debug, Clone, Eq, PartialEq, Group)] // How could I derive Group here as well?
struct AGroup<G: Group>(G);
```

without all this boilerplate:

```
impl<G: Group> Add for AGroup<G>{
    type Output = AGroup<G>;
    fn add(self, other: Self) -> Self {
        AGroup(self.0 + other.0)
    }
}

impl<G: Group> Neg for AGroup<G>{
    type Output = AGroup<G>;
    fn neg(self) -> Self {
        AGroup(-self.0)
    }
}
...
```

Comment: I dont know if it is good practice, but you could implement deref, https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html

Comment: Do you want to result of adding `Group`'s to always return an `AGroup`?

Comment: I just realized I have been assuming `Group` looks something like `trait Group: Add<Output=Self> + Neg<Output = Self> + ... {}` (to make the boilerplate make sense). If that is so, please add that to the answer; if `Group` is substantially different from that, please indicate how, so I can make sure my answer is correct. Thanks!

Comment: @Netwave it's [definitely not](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/predictability.html?highlight=deref#only-smart-pointers-implement-deref-and-derefmut-c-deref)

Comment: Rel: [Automatically implement traits of enclosed type for Rust newtypes (tuple structs with one field)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831573/automatically-implement-traits-of-enclosed-type-for-rust-newtypes-tuple-structs)

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible in Rust today (as of 1.50) or for the foreseeable future.

You *could* write a custom `derive` macro for `Group`. This amounts to writing code that generates the boilerplate, instead of writing the boilerplate itself. It might be worthwhile if you're going to put `#[derive(Group)]` on multiple types. But if you only want automatic implementations for `AGroup<G>`, it'll probably be much shorter and simpler just to write the boilerplate.

The name of the feature you really want is "delegation". It's been [RFCed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1406) a [couple](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2393) of times but never accepted (IMO both RFCs have tried to cover too many different use cases and turned out unwieldy). There are concerns about what syntax is the best, how granular delegation should be, and how easily it might be abused to create brittle "inheritance-like" relationships between data structures.

For now, if you cannot find a different design that doesn't require delegation (such as that suggested in [Netwave's answer](/a/66548456/3650362)), you should probably bite the bullet and write the delegating `impl`s yourself. There are crates such as [`delegate`](https://docs.rs/crate/delegate/0.5.1) and [`ambassador`](https://docs.rs/crate/ambassador/0.2.1) that can make certain delegation patterns easier, but I'm not sure if either of them exactly fit what you're trying to do (more evidence that everybody wants a slightly different form of "delegation").

### Related questions

- [How can I forward/alias/delegate a function to a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59977439/3650362)
- [Implementing a trait for multiple types at once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39150216/3650362)

On implementing `Deref`, which is occasionally suggested as an alternative to delegation:

- [Is it considered a bad practice to implement Deref for newtypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45086595/3650362)
- [Can I use Deref<Target = Other> to inherit trait implementations from Other?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55032618/3650362)

Comment: Just wanted to add that nothing has changed in the meantime, there is still no delegation possible in Rust 1.72 and as far as I'm aware there are also no new RFCs for it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just create a method exposing the inner object interface:

```rust
pub trait Group {
    fn foo(self: &Self){
        println!("Called from group")
    }
}

#[derive (Copy, Debug, Clone, Eq, PartialEq)] // How could I derive Group here as well?
pub struct AGroup<G: Group>(G);

impl<G: Group> AGroup<G> {
    pub fn inner(&self) -> &impl Group {
        &self.0
    }
}

pub struct Test {}
impl Group for Test {}



fn main( ) {
    let a = AGroup( Test {} );
    a.inner().foo();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d9c4c0ed69da4a112552cebcd1b538fd)